# Paginação no codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Galera fiz a paginação no codeigniter e ela funciona com excessão de um detalhe o link da página dois fica url/1, da página três fica url/2 e da primeira só a url. O que faço pra deixa a página dois com url/2? Segue o código:

```
$config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "usuarios";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->usuario->totalRegistros();
    $config["per_page"] = $this->config->item('registros_por_pagina');
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $pagina = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

    $data['usuarios'] = $this->usuario->listarUsuarios($config["per_page"], $pagina);
    $data["paginacao"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
$config ['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Põe isto no seu código.